# colormap on webcam video capture

Tags: matlab, video, webcam, color-mapping

I am currently working for a matlab meets my webcam project. Here is my code:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo');
vidRes = get(vid, 'VideoResolution');
nBands = get(vid, 'NumberOfBands');
hImage = image( zeros(vidRes(2), vidRes(1), nBands));
preview(vid, hImage);
colormap cool;
```

The video was displayed as it is in webcam. However the `colormap cool;` seems no effect in the video. I tried replacing the video by a dummy imag and the `colormap cool;` takes effect.

Is there any way for me to control the colormap of my video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color images (including video frames) are defined using 3 channels, R G B. Colormaps are used when you only have 1 channel of information and MAP a single value to a 3 channel RGB value.

For example:

```
img1 = rand(20,20,3);
imagesc(img); 
colormap hot; % This does nothing because the image has 3 channels

img2 = rand(20,20);
imagesc(img);
colormap hot; % This works because a colormap is being used to map the 1 channel to a color
```

If you want to use a colormap for your video you'll have to select either the R, G, or B channel or create a single channel as a combination of multiple channels.

Comment: Thank you very much. Highly appreciated. By the way is it okay if I ask a sample code for creating a single channel as combination of multiple channel?

Comment: @dmfrl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547029/how-do-i-display-the-red-channel-of-an-image-in-matlab or http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283668